# storing user input to an empty hash

Tags: ruby, save, hash

I'm writing a basic program. I am starting out with an empty hash, and using gets.chomp and want to store the info into the hash so that it can be recalled later (in the same session).

```
runs = {}
puts "how many miles did you run?"
miles = gets.chomp
puts "how long did it take you?"
time = gets.chomp
```

... program continues

Later I would like to have the user enter 'review' to display this (and any others that were entered) as information:

```
runs.each do |miles, time|
   puts "#{miles} miles in #{time} minutes."
end
```

I know I am missing something before/after the "gets.chomp". Any suggestions?

Comment: But you didn't put any value inside the `hash`, and you are attempting to call the hash.. Awesome!! -1

Comment: What you kept hide inside the line *... program continues*.. Ask you question clearly.. We wouldn't guess..

Comment: That's what I'm asking.. I don't want to call the empty hash. How do I "store" those variables in the hash so it's not empty?

Comment: what happens if the user runs the same distance twice?

Comment: That's alright, I just want a total list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a key value pair to a hash, you would use `runs[miles] = time`.

So your code would look something like this:

```
runs = {}
puts "How many miles did you run?"
miles = gets.chomp
puts "How long did it take you?"
time = gets.chomp

runs[miles] = time

# When user enters `review`
runs.each do |miles, time|
    p "#{miles} miles in #{times} minutes."
end
```

That's not the only way to add a key/value pair to a hash, so you can look at all the methods available over in the [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html).

Comment: Thank you @cereal for actually answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

As your program is written, if a user ran the same distance twice (with different times) only the *last* result will be recorded, as a hash cannot store duplicate keys. A better way would be to store it in an array of tuples (== array with two values):

```
runs = []

puts "How many miles did you run?"
miles = gets.chomp
puts "How long did it take you?"
time = gets.chomp
runs << [miles, time]

# ...    

runs.each do |miles, time|
   puts "#{miles} miles in #{time} minutes."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
runs = Hash.new
puts "How many miles did you run?"
runs ["miles"] = gets.chomp
puts "How long did it take you?"
runs ["time"] = gets.chomp

# When user enters `review`
runs.each do |miles, time|
    p "#{miles} miles in #{times} minutes."
end
```